# Client or the client?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, titles

I am a programmer working on a solution composed of a service and a client application which will use it. There will be only the one dedicated application to work with the service.

In our correspondence we often mention the client app. So far I have noted that most of my colleagues call it *Client*, capitalized and without a preceding definite article, like a proper name.

But shouldn't we name it just *the client*? Because *Client* is neither the internal code name nor the official release title. The app has completely different name.

Comment: When it comes to naming, *should* is a matter of opinion. Think of it as your colleagues assigning the nickname *Client* to the client, for simplicity, to avoid confusion with other clients, and because they were not clever enough to name it Francine or Percival or DJ Klyint.

Comment: @choster: I vote for DJ Klyint

Comment: So do I! I'll make a proposal at the next meeting.

Answer (score 1):

They are using *Client* as a nickname - if you come up with something better (*From now on, the client application will be referred to as 'Sheila'*), they'll use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's the client application.

Comment: Hello, Nicola Tancrei. You can greatly strengthen your answer by citing some reference authority that supports your view. Unfortunately, at present, your answer reads as though it were an expression of personal preference unrelated to broader practice.